# MySQL select one field from table WHERE condition is in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, select, union, conditional-statements, where-clause

Tried to find the answer, but still couldn't.. The table is as follows:

```
id, keyword,   value
1   display    15.6
1   harddrive  320
1   ram        3
```

So what i need is something like this.. Select an id from this table where `(keyword="display" and value="15.6") AND (keyword="harddrive" and value="320")`
There's also a possibility that there will be 3 or 4 such keyword conditions which should result into returning one id (one row)

It seems there's something to deal with UNION but i didn't use it before so i can't figure it out

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) problem. Something like the following should do it.

```
SELECT id
FROM your_table
WHERE 
(keyword="display" and value="15.6") OR (keyword="harddrive" and value="320")
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

I'm assuming that your table has appropriate constraints such that it is impossible for there to be a completely duplicated row.  (e.g. there is a PK on `id, keyword`)

Comment: this is it! thank you! and the link is good, i'm already studying it. Perfect :) oh and yes, the duplicated rows are prohibited by all means

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table
WHERE 
(keyword="display" and value=15.6) OR (keyword="harddrive" and value=320)
```