# Mysql query to find ID where multiple condition meet for one column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I would appreciate any help creating this query. I have tried several methods without luck. As my question is somewhat difficult for me to phrase, I will make a simple example of what I want to do. I have data that is structurally similar to the following:

```
ID  TYPE  COLOR
1   A     Blue
1   B     Red
1   C     Green
2   C     Blue 
2   B     Green
```

I want to create a query to return the types if I have an ID with two specific colors. For example I would like to find all the ID that have both Blue and Red. The query would then return:

```
1, A , B
```

The order that A and B is returned is unimportant. The data set is large, I expect many ID's to match both conditions( maybe 50,000 or so). I should note that the type does not correlate to color thus making the problem different from [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419145/select-distinct-values-for-multiple-rows-of-same-id),[as well as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559398/mysql-select-one-field-from-table-where-condition-is-in-multiple-rows).

I think I need to do a subquery of some sort. But really don't know how to proceed, Thank you.

Comment: If you need to ask future questions, putting example data and structures is always a good idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, TYPE FROM types NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT ID FROM types GROUP BY ID HAVING SUM(COLOR='Red') AND SUM(COLOR='Blue')
) t WHERE COLOR IN ('Red', 'Blue')
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/345c7/1/0).

Alternatively, if you're happy to have the types concatenated into a delimited string, you can extract the desired data in a single pass:

```
SELECT   ID, GROUP_CONCAT(TYPE)
FROM     types
WHERE    COLOR IN ('Red', 'Blue')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/345c7/3/0).

Note that, if your table might contain multiple records with the same `(ID, COLOR)` pair, you should replace `COUNT(*)` with the more expensive `COUNT(DISTINCT COLOR)`.

Comment: You can do a sum on a boolean expression (`color='Red'`) in MySQL? How is that defined? I mean, what is the result of summing three `false` and two `true` values?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: boolean expression evaluates to 1 if true, 0 if false; taking the sum therefore results in zero if no group member matches and non-zero if at least one member matches; using the result in the `HAVING` clause casts back to boolean again.  In your example, the result would be `0+0+0+1+1=2`.

Comment: So MySQL doesn't have "real" booleans? (Because `0` and `1` is **not** a boolean).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Can't answer that, but it does have implicit type conversion...  on [Numeric Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/numeric-type-overview.html) (relates more specifically to column data types) the manual states "*`BOOL`, `BOOLEAN` -- These types are synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`. A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true ... However, the values `TRUE` and `FALSE` are merely aliases for `1` and `0`, respectively*", so probably it doesn't have true boolean types.

Comment: Thank you,  I used your second solution and it worked nicely!

Comment: Could you explain to me that the t is after the parentheses of you first solution? I have googled and cant seem to avoid stuff about T-SQL

Comment: @keithchem: It's just an alias for the materialised table.  It could be anything you want, optionally preceded it with `AS`.

Comment: I have slightly altered your quarry to meet my needs ( I actually wanted to quarry if an id had a pair of numbers with in two distinct range). I do have another question with my altered version though... Would it be best to repost the question? I feel odd reposting a question that contains only a slightly modified version of your answer. What I changed is here on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a2dc/3). I basically want all the pairs that meet the condition so for example `4| A,B,D` would be `[4 | A,B][4|A,D] on two different lines.

Comment: @keithchem: Why not also pair `B,D`? Are you only seeking to have every pair of items from each side of the criteria?  Perhaps [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/595c3/1/0) is what you're after?

Comment: Yes!!! that works. For some reason I was insisting on finding the "pair", when you simply meet the two criteria sequentially. That works. You were correct that I wanted a pair from each side of the criteria. I was looking for the the pair (500,10) or (10,500) but not (10,10) or (500,500). Also your version runs ~3x faster on the full database. Thank you very much! I clearly have a lot to learn.