# Trying to find the SQL statement that will return unique parcel number when given different portions of the property address in a web form

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'details' with 70 columns including property address info (column names include parcel_id, loc_strno, loc_strfrac, loc_strdir, loc_strname, loc_strtype, loc_strunit, loc_city, state, zip, country...) Users input address information in web form where form field represents column from dbsomething like INPUT = 
loc_strno:  123
loc_strdir: West
loc_strname: Main
loc_strtype: Street

Desired OUTPUT: the parcel_id (Primary key of the table) matching the address  123 West Main Street = 555-45-6789

Not sure how to query the database.  I am able to save the input address info but not sure of best way to use/compare it to get the parcel_id (primary key).

Web Form collecting address details

```
exports.postSearchedProperty = (req, res, next) => {
const loc_strno = req.body.loc_strno;
const loc_strfrac = req.body.loc_strfrac;
const loc_strdir = req.body.loc_strdir;
const loc_strname = req.body.loc_strname;
const loc_strtype = req.body.loc_strtype;
const loc_strunit = req.body.loc_strunit;
const loc_city = req.body.loc_city;
const state = req.body.state;
const zip = req.body.zip;
const country = req.body.country;
  const searchedproperty = new SearchedProperty(null, loc_strno, loc_strfrac, loc_strdir, loc_strname, loc_strtype, loc_strunit, 
loc_city, state, zip, country);
  property
```

prior questions were helpful but not exact.
[Mysql query to find ID where multiple condition meet for one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299670/mysql-query-to-find-id-where-multiple-condition-meet-for-one-column)
[SQL: how to select a single id ("row") that meets multiple criteria from a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179260/sql-how-to-select-a-single-id-row-that-meets-multiple-criteria-from-a-singl)

Comment: I am confused about what you are asking. Could you provide an example of your desired output given a certain input?

Comment: Thanks William I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would be the problem with something like this?

```
SELECT parcel_id FROM dbsomething
WHERE     loc_strno = ? 
    AND  loc_strdir = ? 
    AND loc_strname = ? 
    AND loc_strtype = ?
```

Where, following your example inputs, the [parameter values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values) would be

1. `'123'`
2. `'West'`
3. `'Main'`
4. `'Street'`

**EDIT**

You have expressed that `req.body` has many properties and you don't know which will be defined. The best solution for this is to use JavaScript logic rather than SQL.

```
var queryList = [];
for (p in req.body) {
    /* iterate through all possible attributes */
    if (req.body[p] !== null) {
        /* include the attribute in the query if it's defined */
        queryList.push(p + ' = ?');
    }
}
const query = 'SELECT parcel_id FROM dbsomething WHERE ' + queryList.join(' AND ');
```

You can follow a similar procedure to set the actual parameter values. By doing this, you can filter only by attributes that are defined.

Comment: that looks good but I wasn't sure if it was necessary to make the fields required or if I can allow searches when they have less specific address - like if they were missing the '123' I was concerned that I wasn't able to find a related tutorial and am anticipating errors with things I haven't considered. thanks William -