# MySQL select one field from an Attributes table WHERE condition is in multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I started here:
[MySQL select one field from table WHERE condition is in multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559398/mysql-select-one-field-from-table-where-condition-is-in-multiple-rows)

This works fine - thank you!

The additional complexity is that I need to search *within* multiple attributes in a single search.

Here's a data snapshot.  The attribute_ids are:

```
1  - language
18 - phone1
19 - phone2
20 - phone3
```

Sample data

```
+-----+------------+--------------+------------------------+
| id  | contact_id | attribute_id | stored_attribute_value |
+-----+------------+--------------+------------------------+
|  15 |          1 |            1 | english                |
|  83 |          5 |            1 | english                |
| 153 |          9 |            1 | english                |
| 197 |         11 |            1 | english                |
| 250 |          3 |            1 | english                |
| 267 |         13 |            1 | tagalog                |
| 303 |         15 |            1 | spanish                |
| 374 |         19 |            1 | spanish                |
| 469 |         17 |            1 | spanish                |
| 490 |         21 |            1 | spanish                |
| 507 |          7 |            1 | english                |
|   9 |          1 |           18 | 983-296-3660           |
|  77 |          5 |           18 | 123-300-3985           |
| 147 |          9 |           18 | 215-857-7105           |
| 191 |         11 |           18 | 123-216-8501           |
| 244 |          3 |           18 | 478-786-4450           |
| 261 |         13 |           18 | 802-118-7211           |
| 297 |         15 |           18 | 998-370-4612           |
| 367 |         19 |           18 | 203-435-4023           |
| 463 |         17 |           18 | 945-519-5355           |
| 481 |         21 |           18 | 425-675-8912           |
| 501 |          7 |           18 | 123-712-6946           |
|  11 |          1 |           19 | 123-653-3722           |
|  79 |          5 |           19 | 396-609-5772           |
| 149 |          9 |           19 | 261-899-1470           |
| 193 |         11 |           19 | 673-452-9545           |
| 246 |          3 |           19 | 760-700-5826           |
| 263 |         13 |           19 | 123-701-7931           |
| 299 |         15 |           19 | 123-445-5874           |
| 369 |         19 |           19 | 711-657-8183           |
| 465 |         17 |           19 | 123-130-2816           |
| 483 |         21 |           19 | 123-391-1234           |
| 503 |          7 |           19 | 123-568-1263           |
| 485 |         21 |           20 | 123-428-6610           |
+-----+------------+--------------+------------------------+
```

So if I were to search for all contacts with language 'english' and phone1 like '123%', the query would be:

```sql
SELECT `contact_id` 
FROM (`contact_attribute_value`) 
WHERE (`attribute_id` = '18' AND `stored_attribute_value` LIKE '123%') 
OR (`attribute_id` = '1' AND `stored_attribute_value` = 'english') 
GROUP BY `contact_id` HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

And I would get 3 results returned: 5, 7, and 11 which is correct.

The challenge is that I want to create a generic phone field in the search interface so that if a user searches for a phone number, they search all three phone fields simultaneously.

So, I wrote the following query:

```sql
SELECT `contact_id` 
FROM (`contact_attribute_value`) 
WHERE (`attribute_id` = '18' AND `stored_attribute_value` LIKE '123%') 
OR (`attribute_id` = '19' AND `stored_attribute_value` LIKE '123%') 
OR (`attribute_id` = '20' AND `stored_attribute_value` LIKE '123%')
OR (`attribute_id` = '1' AND `stored_attribute_value` = 'english') 
GROUP BY `contact_id` HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Conceptually that works, but there are conditions in which it breaks.

The first condition is when a contact has language of 'english' and two phone numbers that match like '123%'.  Here the contact gets a count of 3 and does not show up in the results.

The second condition is when a contact has a language not equal to 'english' and also has two phone numbers that match like '123%'.  In this case, the contact gets a count of 2 and shows up in the results, but that's not what is desired.

I'm sure there's a "hard coded" way of trapping for these conditions in this scenario, but the set of attributes and possible searches is quite large so I need a generalizable solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just taking into account your example and the conditions you explained, I would say that the easiest way to solve this without doing two queries, is with a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact_id
FROM contact_attribute_value AS c
WHERE c.attribute_id IN (18, 19, 20)
AND c.stored_attribute_value LIKE '123%'
AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
            FROM contact_attribute_value AS c1 
            WHERE c1.contact_id = c.contact_id  AND c1.attribute_id = 1 
            AND c1.stored_attribute_value = 'english')
```

With this query, first we check if the contact haves any number that starts with 123, and then the subquery takes care of checking if the contact haves english as his language.

The `DISTINCT` keyword removes dupliciates, so no need for grouping anymore.

Comment: nice one.  So if I were to add another attribute I would need to add another subquery, for example, address.  In fact, I could just put all my conditions in their own subquery.  I tried it and it works. I assume that each subquery costs in terms of performance.

Comment: For each *orthogonal* attribute on your query, you'll need an extra subquery, yes. And yeah, they are suposed to be costly, but idk how much. You probably want to time the diferent options you have, to look for the better one performance wise. Your schema seems nice to generalize some stuff and save space, but for the kind of problem you are exposing, it's probably better to normalize it, that will make your queries a lot easier to design (unless you have another reason to keep your current schema).

Comment: ok - so after running some test, it appears that the subqueries is faster for this schema than the group / having structure.  given the nature of the data and its reuse throughout the application, this schema is the most sound.  .... so thank you for your help with this. much appreciated.  and thanks to @peterm as well for an excellent solution that may work for others with this same problem.

Comment: No probs, glad my answer helped :]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly try

```sql
SELECT c1.contact_id
  FROM contact_attribute_value c1 LEFT JOIN contact_attribute_value c2
    ON c1.contact_id = c2.contact_id  
   AND c2.attribute_id = '18' LEFT JOIN contact_attribute_value c3
    ON c1.contact_id = c3.contact_id  
   AND c3.attribute_id = '19' LEFT JOIN contact_attribute_value c4
    ON c1.contact_id = c4.contact_id  
   AND c4.attribute_id = '20'
 WHERE c1.attribute_id = '1' AND c1.stored_attribute_value = 'english'
   AND (c2.stored_attribute_value LIKE '123%'
    OR  c3.stored_attribute_value LIKE '123%'
    OR  c4.stored_attribute_value LIKE '123%')
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c2b9/10)**

**UPDATE** Improved version with `HAVING` that uses conditional count

```
SELECT `contact_id`
  FROM `contact_attribute_value`
 GROUP BY `contact_id` 
HAVING SUM(CASE  WHEN `attribute_id` = '1'  
                  AND `stored_attribute_value` = 'english' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
   AND (SUM(CASE WHEN `attribute_id` = '18' 
                  AND `stored_attribute_value` LIKE '123%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
       +SUM(CASE WHEN `attribute_id` = '19' 
                  AND `stored_attribute_value` LIKE '123%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
       +SUM(CASE WHEN `attribute_id` = '20' 
                  AND `stored_attribute_value` LIKE '123%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 
;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c2b9/16)**

Comment: Peter -- Thanks so much for your query!  Two things:  1) The data I listed was slightly incorrect in that I was showing the wrong field.  It is now correct.  2) While your query may work, I have about 50 fields to search on and the complexity of generating a query like that would be unmanageable. I believe I can solve this by hitting the database twice but am hoping to avoid that.  P.S. I can't figure out how to add line breaks in my comment!

Comment: @KevinHowardGoldberg Updated the query and sqlfiddle to comply with your updated data. And added improved version of your query. **BTW the correct resultset is 1, 5, 7, 11**. Now, you'll run into complexity pretty fast anyway with that number of fields you need to search on. You can consider to wrap it in a stored procedure to keep that complexity from app layer. And sorry, you can't add line breaks in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  That is the correct result set - yes.  I can see how to extend it as well and makes sense.  It's a more complex query than the other solution - I wonder though if it would be more efficient since it's a single query as opposed to the multiple subqueries.